Vue Js remove /xyz from url
I have a problem where I want to load the favicon from some websites, but I'm having trouble because the URLs have extra parts like "/home". These extra parts, called routes, prevent the favicon from loading properly. I need a way to make a function that automatically removes the route from the URL.
return this.favurl = https://${this.url}/favicon.ico;

Look for static assets. There is no need to manually set such things

It's unknown what's your setup. There's supposed to be properly set , and then there will be no problems loading it from /favicon.ico
